# Is it correct that $-\lfloor0.5\rfloor \ne \lfloor(-0.5)\rfloor$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

As I understand [floor functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions):

$\lfloor (-0.5)\rfloor = -1$

while

$-\lfloor(0.5)\rfloor = -0 = 0$

Am I understanding floor functions correctly?

Comment: Yes, $\lfloor -0.5 \rfloor = -1$ and $-\lfloor 0.5\rfloor = 0$. In general $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor = \begin{cases} 0 & x \text{ is integer }\\ -1, & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. The maximum integer below $-0.5$ is $-1$, and the maximum integer below $0.5$ is 0, so $- \lfloor 0.5 \rfloor = 0$

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to figure out a mistake in a formula that I was using and this was it.  Very surprising.

Comment: You should definitely post the formula in this question - maybe someone on Math SE will be able to figure out where you have made a mistake.

Comment: The formula is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/271808/15915).   I had been told that the mistake was in my inequality but I couldn't see how this was so despite the counter example provided.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck At the time of posting the question wasn't answered. Now I would obviously not persuade the OP to edit their question

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html) agree (you can look at the graphs there). Be careful, though: There's a small chance that some programming language will have floor defined incorrectly for negative inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In general. For positive non integer $x $, If $0 < n < x <n+1$ then $-n-1 <x <-n $.

So....

$[x]=n $ while $[-x]=-n-1=-[x]-1$

But if $x $ is an integer then $[x]=[n]=n=$ and $[-x]=[-n]=-n=-x $.

It seems a little weird but it all makes sense.